# Apache Ignite: Can custom Rest Method be deployed to service grid

Tags: rest, ignite

Just need to check the feasibility if we can deploy our own custom rest method into apache ignite service grid which can be accessed by clients.

Idea is to get the request into my custom rest method exposed, make the relevant changes and send back the response.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It's not trivial to add a method to the existing Ignite REST server but it's fairly straight-forward to have your own end-point running using the Service Grid.

Comment: Thank you so much, could you please guide me to some example of Apache Ignite which enable to expose end point running in service grid

Comment: @user330060 You can specify your own Jetty config in ConnectorConfiguration, and you can add any endpoints there.

Comment: Hi, user330060. Have you implemented such service or found example? There is code snippet for this case using Jetty & Jersey http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/custom-restful-service-using-jetty-server-on-top-of-ignite-grid-to-perform-crud-operations-and-confie-td17453.html

Answer (score 0):

This is my aproach using Ignite service proxy (don't forget disable ignite embedded http or you have to exclude some dependencies):

RESTServiceImpl.java:

```
public class RESTServiceImpl implements RESTService {
    
    @IgniteInstanceResource
    private Ignite ignite;

    @LoggerResource
    private IgniteLogger log;

    private Server jettyServer;

    public void init(ServiceContext ctx) {

        ServletContextHandler context = new
                ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.NO_SESSIONS);
        context.setContextPath("/api");


        jettyServer = new Server(8888);
        jettyServer.setHandler(context);

        ServletHolder jerseyServlet = context.addServlet(ServletContainer.class, "/*");
        jerseyServlet.setInitOrder(0);

        // Tells the Jersey Servlet which REST service/class to load.
        jerseyServlet.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.packages", "services.rest");

    }

    public void execute(ServiceContext ctx) {
        log.info("Starting REST Service");

        try {
            jettyServer.start();
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        log.info("Starting REST Service : OK");
    }

    public void cancel(ServiceContext ctx) {
        log.info("Stopping REST Service on node:" + ignite.cluster().localNode());

        try {
            jettyServer.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

RESTController.java:

```
@Path("/mypath")
public class EventCaseController {

    private Ignite ignite = Ignition.ignite();
    private RESTService restService = ignite.services().serviceProxy(RESTService.SERVICE_NAME,
            RESTService.class, false);

    @GET
    @Path("size")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public JSONObject eventCaseCacheSize() {
         // some logics

     }
}
```